# Laravel Fluent query update or insert based on if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

I have a Laravel Fluent query that looks like the following:

```
$query = DB::connection('mysql_users')->table('users_info');
$exists = $query->where('email', '=', $user->email)-first();

if(is_object($exists)) {
    // update email
}
else {
    // insert email
}
```

The problem is, sometimes $exists is not an object even though the row does exist. I've also tried with is_null() and have had the same issue. What is the correct way to do this check?

Comment: `count($exists) != 0`?

Comment: What is it then if it's not an object? try `dd($exists)`

Comment: @TimLewis: I've actually tried that too. It creates an error when it's null (or whatever it is).

Comment: @lukasgeiter: Ah, familiar face. :) What's dd?

Comment: Hmm. Odd. Try what @lukasgeiter says, do a `dd($exists)` on an email you know exists and one you know that doesn't. Compare those results and go from there. Also, if you use `->get()` followed by `count()` that might make a difference. Hard to say.

Comment: `dd()` stands for *dump 'n' die*. it prints the variable with `var_dump()` and then stops the execution.

Comment: @lukasgeiter: Ah, I see. I'll go test. It's hard to reproduce as it doesn't happen often.

Comment: What's wrong with using the model's `findOrNew()` method

Answer (score 0):

Just check the statement, if its not an object then don't check for one.

```
if($exists = $query->where('email', '=', $user->email)-first()) {
    // update email
}
else {
    // insert email
}
```

Comment: I can see one issue with that; if it does exist and he wants to update that row, he'd have to repeat that query. If it's in a variable, then you wouldn't.

Comment: there you go @Tim Lewis

Comment: How do you update the $exists without querying again? Remember fluent does not allow $exists->update(['foo'=>'bar'])